# React Native: Is it possible to persist native Java variable values on app reload?

Tags: java, react-native, react-native-native-module

Is it possible to maintain the value of Java variables in a custom react native module when reloading the JS? I would like to maintain `components` in the below code for debugging purposes. It persists on onHostResume if the app goes into the background but on reload the value is lost.

```
public class CustomModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModuleWithEvents implements LifecycleEventListener {

    public List<JsonObject> components = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void addComponents(component) {
        // add some components...
        components.add(component);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomModule";
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {
        getReactApplicationContext()
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit("DEBUG_TAG", components.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: The method of storing variables using local storage looks good.

Comment: I reversed the edit as I’m not using Expo at all for my app and this is part of a custom native module which is why I added the current tags

Comment: In the case of the Expo, the React-native is used equally. The more tags involved, the more your expert in the field will see your question.

Comment: My answer to your question is using local storage.

Comment: Thanks but I resolved the issue. I should have set the List as a static class variable so that it is only initialized once rather than initialized every time on reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every reload the JS code is creating a new instance of CustomModule reinitializing components. I should have set the components List as a static class variable so that it is only initialized once.

```
public class CustomModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModuleWithEvents implements LifecycleEventListener {

    public static List<JsonObject> components = new ArrayList<>();

}
```